# Using a linear gradient on all four sides of a <div>

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a box using linear-gradient. I want to have a 7px fade from red to white on all four sides. So far I've got one side (the bottom) working, no problems:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, white, #eb3136 7px); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, white, #eb3136 7px); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, white, #eb3136 7px); 
background: linear-gradient(bottom, white, #eb3136 7px);
```

How do I get that 7px fade to write on the other three sides?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe you try play arround with something like this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: You should use the new `to` syntax instead of the legacy *from* one. Check [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Comment: The easiest way would be to use box-shadow, so gradients will fit at corners : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tdBCj either inset or ouset boxshadow.added  border and outline to show where box and shadow stands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #eb3136 inset;
```

will probably do what you want in a simpler way.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6EREc/

Comment: Thanks heaps, this'll do nicely.  :)

Comment: Just to add on, this is a nice site to bookmark: http://css3generator.com/. Then click on the Box Shadow button.

Answer (score 3):

You can try multiple backgrounds:

```css
background:
    linear-gradient(to top, #eb3136, white 7px, transparent 7px),
    linear-gradient(to right, #eb3136, white 7px, transparent 7px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb3136, white 7px, transparent 7px),
    linear-gradient(to left, #eb3136, white 7px, transparent 7px);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/97NGe/)